# GCP - Proxy .pac File Configuration

Tags: proxy, sdk, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, pac

I would like to know if someone knows how to configure proxy on GCP Sdk.
My proxy is an .pac file, eg http//hostname:port/proxy.pac.

Does anyone know how to set this?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy PAC files are full javascript programs that tell a browser how to send a request. The Google Cloud SDK doesn't support this, [it only support HTTP(s) and SOCKS proxies](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings).

It's quite possible that your PAC file will send all Google Cloud traffic through the same HTTP(s) proxy. You can determine this by reading the PAC function and seeing where it sends traffic to *.googleapis.com <sup>1</sup>. If it is `DIRECT`, no proxy is needed. If it is `PROXY proxy.yourcompany.com:8080` then you can use that domain/port as an HTTP proxy using the settings linked above.

<sup>1</sup> Google cloud SDK does use some other domains, including *.googleusercontent.com, accounts.google.com, firebase.com, appspot.com and others.